# How to deal with 'sort by' on author field (playa) where there are multiple authors

Tags: playa, sort, sorting

I have a project where we display a table of books and a column in that table represents a playa field where 1 or more related authors may be selected. I would really like to then be able to sort on author with the first playa entry for each book being considered the 'primary' author and the sort apply to that...

[image]

The results I get when trying to order by this field appear to be rather random, wondering if this is partially related to [Using Playa field to order channel entries list](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/using-playa-field-to-order-channel-entries-list)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting based on the *contents* of the TD, it would probably be better to set a data attribute to that TD and sort by that value. So instead of...

```
<td>2 Authors<br>Joe Bloggs<br>Bloggsy Malone</td>
```

You would want

```
<td data-primary_author="Joe Bloggs">2 Authors<br>Joe Bloggs<br>Bloggsy Malone</td>
```

Which could be achieved with

```
<td data-primary_author="{exp:playa:parents channel='author' limit='1'}{title}{/exp:playa:parents}">
```

You'd also have to adjust your JavaScript to sort by data attribute rather than contents.

Comment: Very creative idea! Filing this in my memory.